# Java connect Hbase and Phoenix Failed

Tags: java, hbase

HBase and Hadoop is CDH standalone mode in docker. ZK、hbase、phoenix use shell all can operate. java operate zk is OK too.But java cannot operate Hbase and phoenix, Code is OK.
Can anyone help me, Thank you!

```java
    public class HbaseTest {
    public static Configuration conf;
    static{
        conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "master:2181");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
        HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
        boolean exists = admin.tableExists("stu");
        System.out.println(exists);
        admin.close();
    }
}
```

The log after Run code:

```
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=64255: Connection refused: no further information row 'stu,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=master,60020,1620539340415, seqNum=0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.throwEnrichedException(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:418)
    at com.max.hbase.HbaseTest.main(HbaseTest.java:24)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=64255: Connection refused: no further information row 'stu,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=master,60020,1620539340415, seqNum=0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to separate the quorum's address and port

```
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "master");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
```

Also, are you sure that your zookeeper is on the master node? The first property should not be the master address, but the zookeeper quorum (separated by comma, if it's more than one address). I suppose you specified "master" because you are co-locating the master and the single zookeeper node?

Comment: Yeah, zookeeper is standalone mode too，it can be operated by Java client。Win10 System hosts master ip is 192.168.31.179， the docker hosts master ip is 172.17.0.2。I can make sure the ip is the main problem。But have not resolve it

Comment: Not sure how that would work under docker, but avoid using IP addresses. Add IP/host mapping entries into the hosts file (whatever is the Win equivalent of /etc/hosts on Linux). In general, to make sure you can actually reach the right hosts on the right ports, I'd try simple telnet first to make sure the connections actually get established.